# iOS Swift combine two Strings in alphabetical order to create one larger String

Tags: ios, swift, string

Say I have two strings

```
var s1 = "zoseuhfose"
var s2 = "dsdfnsjldfns"
```

I want to combine the two to make one string but I want them to be in alphabetical order. So it would look like this

```
dsdfnsjldfnszoseuhfose
```

Currently I am doing it like this, but I wanted to know if there was a cleaner/ better way

```
let array = [s1,s2].sorted(by: <)
let string = array[0] + array[1]
```

Comment: What do you mean by cleaner/better?

Comment: Meaning is it necessary to use an array? is that the best solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`join`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945737-joined) the array

```
let string = [s1,s2].sorted(by: <).joined()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
let res = [s1,s2].sorted(by: <).joined(separator:"") // joined
```

for 2 only may be also

```
let res = s1 < s2 ? s1 + s2 : s2 + s1
```